# Textbox value not changing on posting

Tags: php, html

I created a textbox in the following manner

```
<input type="text"  name="email" id="email" class="text_inp2" value="Email" onclick="if(this.value=='Email'){this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email';}" />
```

So, that it shows the default text in textbox as `Email` and when I edit it something like `admin@stackoverflow.com` and when I submit (i.e. PHP Post function) it still posting the value as `Email` but not `admin@stackoverflow.com` I don't want to use Query String method. Is there anyway I can get rid of it by using simple PHP Post function.

Comment: Because `value=''` is the default input. You will need to manipulate your new text within the `value=''`

Comment: I agree with @MatRt http://jsfiddle.net/wgshs/ -- look into the HTML `placeholder` attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the input `placeholder` attribute and just including something like http://widgetulous.com/placeholderjs/ for older browsers.

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

Has the exact effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
onchange="
if(this.value === this.defaultValue){
    this.value = '';
}
else if (this.value === '') {
    this.value = this.defaultValue;
}"
```

or use the [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute for those pesky old browsers…

I found this in one of my projects I'm working on, not sure if it works, but if you have modernizer you can try this out

```
if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() === $(this).prop('placeholder')){
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() === '' || $(this).val() === $(this).prop('placeholder')){
            $(this).addClass('placeholder');
            $(this).val($(this).prop('placeholder'));
        }
    }).blur();
    $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function(){
        $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() === $(this).prop('placeholder')){
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: shorthand `onChange="this.value = (this.value === this.defaultValue) ? '' : this.defaultValue;"`